# Ads not showing in published app

Tags: windows-phone-7, ads

My app is published in the Windows Phone Store, but it does not receive any ads. 
I have used a hard-coded AdControl like the following:

```
<UI:AdControl Name="adControl1"
                          Grid.Row="2"
                          Width="480"
                          Height="80"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          ApplicationId="-----"
                          AdUnitId="-----"
                          IsAutoRefreshEnabled="True" 
                          />
```

I created the required ad unit using the Dev Center (as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/help/jj206730%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)).
I have also declared these capabilities in the WMAppManifest.xml:

```
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_SENSORS" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT" />
</Capabilities>
```

I downloaded my own app from Windows Phone Store, and what I get when I launch the app is a rectangle with a slim white border, in the space reserved for the adUnit, and after 2 or 3 seconds it disappears, and nothing happens.

My app was published 2 days ago, if this helps.

Has anybody else got the same problem? I am in despair :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after subscribing to the error event of the AdControl, I found out that the relevant error message was "no ads available".

After changing my phone's region format to  "English (US)" and restarting the device, the ads were being displayed as expected.